# How is mlb.com's ">.500" record calculated?

Tags: baseball, statistics, mlb

On [Major League Baseball's Standings page](https://www.mlb.com/standings), one of the fields is headed `>.500`: "Record against >.500 teams".

Is this the record in games against teams whose record was above .500 when the game was played, or games against teams whose record is above .500 now?

Answer (score 2):

Current record, not at the time of the game.

For example, the White Sox are "6-9" against .500 teams; that includes 4-4 against CLE, 2-2 against BOS, and 0-3 against NYY.  However, the KC Royals were over .500 for several of their games, the Mariners even were over .500 for the first game they played, etc.; while CLE, BOS, and NYY were all over .500 for all of the games they played against the White Sox.